# C# two double quotes

Tags: c#, string-literals

I want to print two double quotes in C# as the output. How to do this?

I mean the output should be: `"" Hello World ""`

Answer (score 22):

```
Console.WriteLine("\"\" Hello world \"\"");
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(@""""" Hello world """"");
```

Comment: Ah, you just beat me. Such a simple question, and so many incorrect answers!

Comment: What does 4 double quote ("""") mean?

Comment: @Monish "" is a single double quote within a @"..." verbatim string literal.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to put double quotes in a string you need to escape them with a `\`

eg:

```
string foo = "here is a \"quote\" character";
```

If you want to literally output `"" Hello World ""` then you'd need:

```
string helloWorld = "\"\" Hello World \"\"";
output(helloWorld);
```

(where output is whatever method you are using for output)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to escape the quotes:

```
var greeting = "\"Hello World\"";
```

Answer (score 2):

you can output with the `@`, which will automatically escape special characters.

```
string output = "\"\" Hello World \"\"";

string output = @""""" Hello World """"";
```

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use special character which are exist in you language add \ before that character then special character start behaving as a string. In your case use like this

```
\"Hello word\"
```

Out put

```
 "Hello word"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have to do this often and you would like this to be cleaner in code you might like to have an extension method for this.

This is really obvious code, but still I think it can be useful to grab and make you save time.

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Put a string between double quotes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value to be put between double quotes ex: foo</param>
    /// <returns>double quoted string ex: "foo"</returns>
    public static string PutIntoQuotes(this string value)
    {
        return "\"" + value + "\"";
    }
```

Then you may call foo.PutIntoQuotes() or "foo".PutIntoQuotes(), on every string you like.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Escape them:

```
Console.WriteLine("\"Hello world\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a backslash before the double quotes: `\"`

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("\"\"Hello world\"\"");
```

The backslash ('\') character precedes any 'special' character that would otherwise be interpreted as your code instead of as part of the string to be output. It's a way of telling the compiler to treat it as a character part of a string as opposed to a character that would otherwise have some sort of purpose in the C# language.

Answer (score 0):

Using a @-char before the 'normal' double quotes will result in printing every special char between those dubble quotes

```
string foo = @"foo "bar"";
```

Comment: In a verbatim string (`@""`) you need to use 2 quote characters, i.e. `""`. What you have is wrong. The OP would want something like `@""""" Hello World """""`.

Comment: Indeed. the double quote is in fact the only special char in an "@string" (I forget the real name for them). This is becasue clearly an @ is the terminator of the string so it needs to be escaped if being used to not terminate a string.

Answer (score -2):

`StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("\"Hello World \"");
string s = sb.ToString();`

Comment: Why would you use a `StringBuilder` for escaping a `string`?