# How to double-quote a string in C#

Tags: c#

I want to produce a string like this: `"blabla"`

I tried wrapping it in single quotes: `"'blabla'"`, but that produces `'blabla'`. How can I wrap a string in double-quotes?

Comment: can you provide the code you have written?

Comment: I think you should have used the word _quote_ in the question text.

Comment: Copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582781/c-sharp-two-double-quotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string s = "\"blabla\"";
```

This will keep the " inside the string

Comment: The only thing it will do is keep the code from compiling. :) EDIT: Original code was `string s = "\"blabla"\";` I kind of come out like an idiot not that it is corrected. :D

Answer (score 18):

I'm assuming (big assumption since the question was unclear) that you want to have double quotes inside your string. For that, you can use the [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) syntax.

```
string s = @"""my string""";
```

You can also manually escape the double quotes:

```
string s = "\"my string\"";
```

### Other Examples (from MSDN)

```
string a = "hello, world";                  // hello, world
string b = @"hello, world";               // hello, world
string c = "hello \t world";               // hello     world
string d = @"hello \t world";               // hello \t world
string e = "Joe said \"Hello\" to me";      // Joe said "Hello" to me
string f = @"Joe said ""Hello"" to me";   // Joe said "Hello" to me
string g = "\\\\server\\share\\file.txt";   // \\server\share\file.txt
string h = @"\\server\share\file.txt";      // \\server\share\file.txt
string i = "one\r\ntwo\r\nthree";
string j = @"one
two
three";
```

Comment: `@""my string""` = big problem.

Comment: I didn't downvote.. but perhaps you meant `string s = @"""my string""";`.. double-double-quotes..

Comment: Yes, typo on my part (the reference I linked to shows the correct way). I've fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

```
 s= "\"" + blabla+ "\"";
```

Comment: I don't think that one exists :P

Comment: Yes Andrew...Updated my answer as well!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
string mystring = "\"blablabla\"";
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way. string str = "\"blabla\"";

Answer (score 1):

string str = "\"blablabla\"";
or
string str = "\"" + blablabla+ "\"";