# Multiline text with "-signs

Tags: c#, parsing

How do I give a string the a multiline text with "-signs in as value?

I want to declare the content of a file as a static string for a test and the issue is that the content uses "" for its values.

It looks something like this:

```
PLCPort = "1" 
PLCBaudRate = "11600"
PLCDataBits = "8" 
PLCStopBit = "0"
```

I've tried using `@""` for the multiline but then the "-signs ruins my day. Is there a way to escape the "-signs while using `@""`?

Comment: Your example strings don't represent what you want, or don't exhibit the problem.

Comment: See my answer here for a variety of escape options:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292652/how-to-double-quote-a-string-in-c-sharp/14292665#14292665

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a `"` character in a verbatim string literal by writing `""`:

```
@"I have a single double quote: ""!"
```