# String.Format store double quotes inside string

Tags: c#, string

I want to represent the following string:

```
aaaa,23,"something inside double quotes", 99, 8, 7
```

I was thinking to do this using `String.Format`:

```
StringBuilder.AppendLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}",
    item.one, item.two, item.three, item.four, item.five, item.six));
```

I need to wrap third argument `{2}` with double quotes.

Comment: Related: [How to double-quote a string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292652/how-to-double-quote-a-string-in-c-sharp/14292665#14292665)

Answer (score 35):

```
string.Format("{0}, {1}, \"{2}\", {3}, {4}, {5}", ...);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do like this :

```
string.Format("{0},{1},\"{2}\",{3},{4},{5}"
   , item.one
   , item.two
   , item.three
   , item.four
   , item.five
   , item.six);
```

Here is a good link where you can read more about this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k4fw5.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You should add `\` before qoutes:

```
stringbuilder.AppendLine(string.Format("{0},{1},\"{2}\",{3},{4},{5}", item.one, item.two, item.three, item.four, item.five, item.six));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put `\` symbol to indicate escape sequence followed by a reserved characters (usually \n, \0, \t, \r, \", etc)