# Replacing double quotes with html quote tags for a given string in C#

Tags: c#, html, string

Given a C# string like: `var str = "This string \"contains\" double quotes.";`

I'd like to transform it to: `var str = "This string <q>contains</q> double quotes.";`

I've got a solution that loops through and string.replaces the double quotes with `<q>` then I loop through that and make every other `<q>` a closing `</q>` tag.  I have a feeling there's a better way or more understandable way to do this though.

Comment: Have you tought of using regular expression ?

Comment: are you familiar with the string `Lieteral sign @` here are some examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582781/c-sharp-two-double-quotes also could you perhaps show your loops as well so that we can see if you are doing what's expected correctly or not.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that your quotes are well formed (ie that you will never have a `"` without a matching partner?

Comment: @DJKRAZE: I'm not sure literals would help here. It would just mean that the example would escape the quotes as `""` instead of `\"`. I personally find the latter to be more readable if all other things are equal.

Comment: I agree.. I was just trying to get a better understanding on how the OP was truly using it or wanting to use it.. for I currently use something similar when working with .aspx pages and html tags.. but you know how it is when reading some of these posts ..users think that we can see or understand exactly what it is they are currently looking at on the PC's

Comment: @Chris Yes, I'm guaranteed matching pairs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use Regex

```
var str = "This string \"contains\" double \"aaaaa\"quotes."; 

var str2 = Regex.Replace(str,@"""(.+?)""", m => "<b>" + m.Groups[1].Value + "</b>");
```

Comment: that a good example that will work assuming the OP understands RegEx `+1` though

Comment: This is very succinct and handles my test cases.  Thanks!  Edit: Just had to change your <b>'s to <q>'s of course.