# Double quotes in C language

Tags: c, escaping

Whenever we need to print double quotes using backslash (escape character) do we have to use it twice while opening the quotes and closing it or just once for both.

i.e like this:

```
printf("  \" \"  ");
```

or like this:

```
printf("  \"  " ");
```

which one is correct?

I need to print (`“Whatever!” He said “The Sparrows are flying again.”`)

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582781/c-sharp-two-double-quotes

Comment: If the braces are also to be printed, you gotta use `printf("\(\"Whatever! \" He said \" The sparrows are flying  again. \"\")");`

Comment: `printf("  \"  " ");` should generate a compiler error.

Comment: _need to print_ sample conatins smart quotes and not `"`.  Is that the issue?

Answer (score 1):

For each double-quote you wish to appear within the string, you need both the backslash and the double quote.

Answer (score 0):

You escape whatever quote you wish to be ignored as code and used as string.
So in your case it would look like:

```
printThis(“\"Whatever!\” He said \“The Sparrows are flying again.\”");
```

Comment: `\“` is not a defined escape sequence.  OP is using smart quotes.

Comment: I will argue that the OP never said anything about "smart quotes" even if that is what came out when the post rendered.  MSWord does convenient stuff like that.  C, however, does not.  If the OP had asked about smart quotes, you would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

the backslash is what allows you to use double quotes and other special charachters. For each one, you should use a single backslash:

```
printf("\"") --> "
printf("\'") --> '
printf("\\") --> \
```

and so on

so  `printf("\“Whatever!\” He said \“The Sparrows are flying again.\”")` would give you your desired output

**EDIT:** As Chux mentioned, `”` is no regular double quotes  `"` and in this case there is no need for a backslash and `printf("“Whatever!\” He said \“The Sparrows are flying again.”")` would suffice. *BUT*, using the backslash would not cause a misbehaviour even though the double quotes are "smart quotes"

Comment: `\“` is not a defined escape sequence.  OP is using smart quotes.

Comment: Thanks. didn't see that

Comment: Embarrassing to post code that compiles with a warning like "unknown escape sequence: '\224'".  To my chagrin I've made similar mistakes too often.  BTW _using the backslash would not cause a misbehaviour even though the double quotes are "smart quotes"_ is not supported by the C spec.

Comment: yeah... compiled it in a hurry online... no warnings there :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a double-quote as recognized by the C compiler: `"`. None of the following are: `“”`. See the difference?

Thus, your code should read, simply:

```
printf("“Whatever!” He said “The Sparrows are flying again.”\n");
```

If you don't want to use the "smart" quotes, you'll need to change to regular quotes and escape *all* of them:

```
printf("\"Whatever!\" He said \"The Sparrows are flying again.\"\n");
```